# MATLAB Accessing data in one .m file from another .m file

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to access data generated in one .m file from another. What I am trying to do is I have one .m call it A.m where I have loaded a large amount of data from a .txt file and broken it up into a structure with various fields. Since this takes up a large amount of space in the script I would like to create another .m file call it B.m, in which I can access the structure created in A.m and plot and perform calculations in B.m. So, basically I want to access a structure created in A.m from B.m. Is this possible?

-Thanks

Comment: Yes that would be very easy with preferentially functions or global variables for example. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html

Comment: Yes, as long as they use the same workspace. Or they are global. Or you can write it to file and then read it in from where ever. There's probably more ways to do it still. What have you tried to so far?

Comment: In `B` do a `evalin('caller','A')`

Answer (score 1):

There are some things to think of here. First, to limit scope, do not use scripts: use functions instead. Calling a script from another script mainly add code to the first script and have nothing to do with scope. However, by using this method, your code becomes hard to read and understand. If you want that all code to be in the same scope I would recommend you keep all the code in the same m-file.

A function however have a **function scope** and unless a variable is declared global it can only be passed into this scope by using function input arguments. Also, the only way to return values is to use function output arguments.

```
function [out1, out2,...] = myFun(in1,in2,...)
out1 = in1*in2;
out2 = in2.^2;
...
```

Now to the tricky part. The variable passed into the function is passed as "copy on write", meaning that the variables are always passed as a reference unless they are modified inside the script. When using structs, only the field that is modified is copied. This can have consequences for your program as well. Since you say your data is large, changing too many fields in the struct in the same function may cause memory overflow.

Anyway, if you only uses script you do not need to pass any data, since the scope is not affected. However, I recommend you to use functions and pass the struct as an input argument. If this was not what you asked for, please comment on this answer.